# Upgrading Web App from 3.1 to 6.0 on Net Core Causes Ajax call issue

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-core-6.0

So i recetly upgraded our application from Net core 3.1 to 6.0. So i updated the framework from 3.1 to 6.0 and updated the package references after that Ajax calls stopped working. It does not reach controller and returns HTML on success. Below is my action in controller.
`[HttpPost] public JsonResult SamplePostCall(string PostData) { return Json(PostData); }`

`$.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: "/Home/SamplePostCall", data: { PostData: "Sample Post Data" }, success: function(response) { console.log(response); }, error: function(err){ console.log(err); } });`

success function return current page html in it.
[image]

Comment: I am not sure why you get this situation, Have you checked the URL when you send the ajax?

Comment: as shown here URL is the same "/Home/{ActionName}" and it was working fine on 3.1 it stopped working when I upgraded the project to 6.0

Comment: From the information you provided in your question, I don't find anything caused this error, Does all the actions in home controller can't be accessed without route attribute?

Comment: Yes, Not only the home controller but all the controller's actions are not accessible without route attributes. event the actions from the URLs are not accessible without route and it happens only because of the version upgrade. if we create a new project in net 6.0 it works fine. still not able to find any reason why this happens.

Comment: From your description, Maybe there is something wrong in your route template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it by adding the route on Http call attribute on controller. So basically i had to update my old code with route like below and it works now. Hope this helps someone else too.
but Do anyone know why this happened? did they changes anything in 6.0 that cause this? on older version it works fine.

[HttpPost("/Home/SamplePostCall")]

```
public JsonResult SamplePostCall(string PostData)
{
   return Json(PostData);
}
```